# How to get Client IP from UDP Transport in Mule ESB?

Tags: udp, mule, clientip

I'm trying to get the client IP and socket of a UDP package and save it in a Flowvar variable using the MEL code

```
#[message.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS]
```

However this variable is always null, I have been able to make it work on TCP transport, does anyone know how to get the remote client address in UDP?

This is my XML file:

```
<mule xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata"  xmlns:udp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/udp" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/udp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/udp/current/mule-udp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/amqp/current/mule-amqp.xsd">
<udp:connector name="UDP" validateConnections="true" keepSendSocketOpen="true" doc:name="UDP" broadcast="true"/>
<flow name="udpFlow">
<udp:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="172.22.20.103" port="4040" connector-ref="UDP" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="UDP" metadata:id="9260547c-3b58-4ebd-953e-fd3e7bb063f3"/>
<object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
<set-variable variableName="source" value="#[message.inboundProperties.MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS]" metadata:id="6a72ad72-167f-44da-9f3d-75143c5c0a2f" doc:name="Variable"/>
<set-payload value="#[flowVars.source] dice #[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

UPDATE:
I solve the Address issue with the MEL code

```
#[message.inboundProperties['packet.address']]: #[message.inboundProperties['packet.port']]
```

Thanks to David Dossot for his help.

Comment: Don't thank me, I didn't realize the `udp` prefix wasn't prepended to the `packet.address` property name, as it's usually the case for other other transports, and gave you a wrong name. You solved it on your own :)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#[message.inboundProperties['packet.address']]
```

Comment: Still returns null... Where did you find the 'udp.packet.address' property?  it doesn't appear in the DataSense Explorer

Comment: Here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/transports/udp/src/main/java/org/mule/transport/udp/UdpMuleMessageFactory.java#L51

Comment: I can´t figure out how the UdpMuleMessageFactory.java is related with the 'udp.packet.address' property however if I try a made up property name I get the same null result, so I guess 'udp.packet.address' doesn't exists as a property.

By checking the UdpMessageReceiver.java, I realize that the property MULE_REMOTE_CLIENT_ADDRESS is created in the run() method. This appear to be failing

Comment: It's related via `UdpConnector.ADDRESS_PROPERTY` right on the line that I've sent a link to. The code suggests that `packet.getAddress()` can be `null` so it is maybe not always possible to retrieve this address.

Comment: The current server is .net based and it receives the clients addresses fine, so there shouldn't be any problem with the packages, there must be some config wrong with Mule. The client address is a must for us.